# Ignore ExecStartPre sleep for ad-hoc systemctl starts

Tags: systemctl

I have a PDF Rendering custom application, I have successfully created a systemctl service for it. I have successfully configured the ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 30 to delay the start by 30 seconds.

Unfortunately searching the web and Linux documentation I cannot find a way to start the service immediately if I want to run it manually on an ad-hoc basis. I know I could always comment out the ExecStartPre line in the service file but it would save time if I didn't have to.

Appreciate any pointers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create another service for the delay and use dependencies to run the PDF rendering service after it. Now you can either start the new service when you need the delay, or the PDF rendering service directly.

Comment: Of course - the solution is super simple then. Thank you.